# Random rotations in SO(N) to get uniformly distributed dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

I have a vector $v_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ on the unit sphere. The vector is constructed by sampling each element from a standard normal distribution and normalizing the final result.

Now what I want to do is generate other vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ on the unit sphere such that the "angle" between the vectors is uniformly distributed, that is $cos^{-1}(v \cdot v_{0})$ is uniformly distributed. To do this, I've been generating random rotation matrices in $SO(N)$ using [`scipy.stats.special_ortho_group`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.special_ortho_group.html) and rotating $v_{0}$ with these matrices to get $v$.

I'm observing a very curious phenomenon with this procedure, which is that the resulting distribution of $cos^{-1}(v \cdot v_{0})$ is normally distributed! And it appears to be centered at 90 degrees. I've attached a histogram of $cos^{-1}(v \cdot v_{0})$ for 3000 samples of this procedure with $N = 22$.

[image]

Could someone provide intuition why the result is normally distributed? How could I generate a result which is uniformly distributed from $0$ to $2\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get by applying to a vector $v$ a matrix from a uniform distribution of  rotation matrices is a uniform distribution of vectors. Notice that the vast majority of vectors form wide-angles with respect to any given vector.
[image]

There's simply more space at the equator of the sphere than there is at the top or bottom. So more vectors tend to form wide-angles with the top vector (or any other vector).

You do however get a uniform distribution of angles for $N=2$. To get a uniform distribution of angles with respect to $v_{0}$ at higher dimensions, you need to form new vectors from your $v$ vectors: $$v_{1} = v- \langle v,v_{0} \rangle v_{0}\\v_{2} = \frac{v_{1}}{|v_{1}|}$$

You will then have $v_{0}\perp v_{2}$. Then you select a random number from $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ and compute $$v_{3} = v_{0} \cos(\theta) + v_{2} \sin(\theta)$$ The $v_{3}$ should give you uniform angles with respect to the original vector $v_{0}$.

Comment: The intuition is clear and so is the algorithm, thanks a lot. With this procedure I believe I can actually skip the computation of a rotation matrix in $SO(N)$ and directly generate random vectors $v$ in the same way that $v_{0}$ is randomly generated. This saves some computation.